# How to keep a Mutable List with the previous data added in a view Model class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have two classes: one is the viewModel (ShoesViewMode.ktl) to keep the data and the other is the Fragment to show the data.(ShoesList.kt )

ShoesList has a mutableList of words and I recover it from the ShoesList to show in a scrollview.

I get a new word from an EditText from a Fragment -> Click on Save button -> Pass this word through nave Args to ShoesDetails -> save it in the ShoesViewModel -> Recover it and show in the Fragment.

The problem is that every time I add a new word, the list doesn't keep the last one added. It's like if the mutableList was always recreated.

I would like to go back the screen and add a new word, and a new word and see the previous words added in the list.

How can I keep the words added previously?

ShoesViewModel.kt

```
class ShoesViewModel(_newShoe: String?=null): ViewModel() { 

    private var _shoesList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<String>>()
    
    init {
        //receives the score when the class is instanciated
        _shoesList.value = mutableListOf(
            "trade",
            "calendar",
            "sad",
            "desk",
            "guitar",
            "home",
            "railway",
            "zebra",
            "jelly",
            "car",
            "crow",
            "trade",
            "bag",
            "roll"
        )
    }

    val shoesList: LiveData<MutableList<String>>
        get() = _shoesList
fun save (newShoe: String){
    _shoesList.value?.add(newShoe)

}
```

ShoesList. kt  // FRAGMENT to show data

> val shoesListArgs by navArgs()
> viewModelFactory = ShoeViewModelFactory(shoesListArgs.newShoe)
> viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this,   viewModelFactory).get(ShoesViewModel::class.java)

> ```
>     //get the view Model //pass to the variable in the xml
>     binding.shoesViewModel = viewModel
>     binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
>
>
>     viewModel.save(shoesListArgs.newShoe) //save new Shoe to the List
>
>     //keeps track of shoesList.  This is an OBSERVER
>     viewModel.shoesList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{ shoesList ->
>         loadShoes(shoesList)
>          })
>
>
>     //actig to floating button
>     binding.buttonFloating.setOnClickListener{ view:View ->
>         view.findNavController().navigate(ShoesListDirections.actionShoesListToShoesDetails())
>     }
>
>     return binding.root
> }
>
> private fun loadShoes(list:MutableList<String>){
>         for(shoe in list){
>             val newTextViewShoe = TextView(context)
>             newTextViewShoe.text = shoe // add TextView to LinearLayout
>             binding.linearlayoutShoelist.addView(newTextViewShoe)
>         }
> }
> ```
>
> }

I save a new word, the Fragment changes and list shows the new word. When I go back to the screen to save a new word, it saves the new word, but the previous on disappears.

Answer (score 0):

In method save You need:

```
fun save(newShoe: String) {

   if (shoeList.value.isNullOrEmpty){
        shoeList.value = mutableListOf(newShoe)
   }
   else {
       shoesList.value = shoesList.value.add(newShoe)
   }
}
```

Your problem is that You are trying to set data to the list rather than livedata by calling livedata.value.add(). Your **value** here is getValue() method, that does nothing but gives you value. If You need to update a value in livedata, then You go:

```
liveData.value = newValue
```

Whether this means setValue() method. Additionally, if You want to set data from another thread than main, use **postValue()**:

```
liveData.postValue(newValue)
```

Comment: but it's a list of shoes. Can I use list.value = newValue? Shouldn't I add the newValue to the list? I will try.